# JavaScript - getElementsByClassName works for one function but not the other

Tags: javascript, function, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to code a simple page where each click will change the pricing on the website using getElementsByClassName.

This is working :

```
<script>
function monthly() {
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    price[0].innerHTML = "$10";
    price[1].innerHTML = "$20";
    price[2].innerHTML = "$30";
    price[3].innerHTML = "$40";
}

</script>
<button onclick="monthly()">Monthly</button>
<button onclick="1year()">1 year</button>
<button onclick="2year()">2 year</button>
<button onclick="3year()">3 year</button>
<br>
<span class="price">$1</span><br>
<span class="price">$2</span><br>
<span class="price">$3</span><br>
<span class="price">$4</span><br>
```

Not working after adding 1year():

```
<script>
function monthly() {
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    price[0].innerHTML = "$10";
    price[1].innerHTML = "$20";
    price[2].innerHTML = "$30";
    price[3].innerHTML = "$40";
}

function 1year() {
    var price2 = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    price2[0].innerHTML = "$8";
    price2[1].innerHTML = "$16";
    price2[2].innerHTML = "$24";
    price2[3].innerHTML = "$32";
}

</script>
<button onclick="monthly()">Monthly</button>
<button onclick="1year()">1 year</button>
<button onclick="2year()">2 year</button>
<button onclick="3year()">3 year</button>
<br>
<span class="price">$1</span><br>
<span class="price">$2</span><br>
<span class="price">$3</span><br>
<span class="price">$4</span><br>
```

Does anyone know why?

TIA.

Comment: if you browser console, you can find: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function or variable in JavaScript cannot start with a number.

Identifiers must start with either a dollar sign ($), an underscore (_) or a unicode character.

In your case,

```
<button onclick="1year()">1 year</button>
<button onclick="2year()">2 year</button>
<button onclick="3year()">3 year</button>
```

All 3 functions are invalid.

Comment: you are my life saviour! I have been scratching my head and couldn't figure out why! All working now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Richard Hamilton, this is the full working code snipplet.

```
<script>
function monthly() {
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    price[0].innerHTML = "$10";
    price[1].innerHTML = "$20";
    price[2].innerHTML = "$30";
    price[3].innerHTML = "$40";
}

function annually() {
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    price[0].innerHTML = "$8";
    price[1].innerHTML = "$16";
    price[2].innerHTML = "$24";
    price[3].innerHTML = "$32";
}

</script>
<button onclick="monthly()">Monthly</button>
<button onclick="annually()">1 year</button>
<br>
<span class="price">$1</span><br>
<span class="price">$2</span><br>
<span class="price">$3</span><br>
<span class="price">$4</span><br>
```